# How to encode a string in UTF-8 from a ResultSet encoded in latin1

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, resultset, iso-8859-1

I'm writing an application (uses UTF-8) that need read/write to a second database of an external application (uses ISO-8859-1).

```java
try {
    // data in latin1
    String s = rs.getString("sAddrNameF");
    System.out.println(s); // shows "Adresse d'exp�dition"
    byte[] data = s.getBytes();
    String value = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("data in UTF8: " + value);
    // The expected result should be "Adresse d'expédition"
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is not working, I also still need do the opposite conversion (writing on the database). If anybody know an elegant solution to dealing with different encoding in the same application please let me know, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm using UTF-8, the IntelliJ is using UTF-8 as a standard

Comment: any trick to discovery the encoding of a file? because I just restore a database script backup. `mysql -uroot -p < dbscript.sql`

Comment: Try `System.out.println("é\u00E9");`  Only if those `éé` are correctly shown, there is a problem. The console is unreliable as it uses its own encoding. Fiddling with bytes is the wrong approach here. More the java JDBC driver transfer protocol's encoding.

Comment: Any programmers editor like Notepad++ or JEdit will do for recognizing the encoding.

Comment: Try setting your default locale to latin1 equivalent and then run your code. You should see your system out printing correctly. If you do then you db and the value itself is fine.

Answer (score 6):

```
String s = rs.getString("sAddrNameF");
System.out.println(s); // shows "Adresse d'exp�dition"
```

This means that the string is either already corrupted in the database, or you're connecting to the database with the wrong encoding (such as passing `characterEncoding=utf8` with MySQL).

There's no such a thing as converting String from one encoding to another. Once you have a `String` it's always UTF-16.

If it's just a configuration problem, you don't need to worry. The `rs.getString()` will return proper Strings and `PreparedStatement.setString()` will make sure Strings are properly saved in the database.

[What you should know about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: All right, is working now, I believe the original file (script .sql exported) was modified and saved in UTF-8 by someone in the project directory using IntelliJ. I just export from the scratch and restore the backup file and is working now. @Kayaman Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

String value =  new String(data,"ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score -1):

We need to mension string as **StandardCharsets.UTF_8**

```
try {
        // data in latin1
        String s = rs.getString("sAddrNameF");
        System.out.println(s); // shows "Adresse d'exp�dition"
        byte[] data = rs.getBytes("sAddrNameF");
        String value = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("data in UTF8: " + value);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The function getBytes takes also a Charset or just string with the desired encoding.

```
byte[] data = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
// or
byte[] data = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```