# Calling a stored procedure from java I get ? for a string that contains a greek character

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm having a table in `mysql` that contains a field named strength_unit_code that has the value `μg`.

I have a `stored procedure` to retrieve that value. From `mysql workbench` I get the value properly.

When I'm trying to retrieve data from java calling the `stored-procedure` I get `?g`.

The table collation is `utf8 - default collation`.

I'm getting the value using `rs.getString("strength_unit_code")`.

I'm using mysql version 5.7.14, java version 1.8.0_171 and JDBC driver 5.1.40.

This is my jdbc connection URI:

```
this.db_connect_string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
        this.userName = "test";
        this.password = "*****";

    }

    protected Connection getDBMySQLCon() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            return DriverManager.getConnection(this.db_connect_string+"?useSSL=false",  this.userName, this.password);
}
```

Comment: Which versions of MySQL, Java and JDBC driver do you use?

Comment: @PowerStat I edited my question to include them.

Comment: Share your JDBC connection URI (exclude password). Do you have some initialization done on connection like `SET NAMES utf8` ?

Comment: @rkosegi I edited my question.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440538/3021395